# What does fit() exactly does here?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-fitting

Well, basically i want to know what does the fit() function does in general, but especially in the pieces of code down there.

Im taking the Machine Learning A-Z Course because im pretty new to Machine Learning (i just started). I know some basic conceptual terms, but not the technical part.

CODE1:

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

missingvalues = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean', verbose = 0) 

missingvalues = missingvalues.fit(X[:, 1:3])

X[:, 1:3] = missingvalues.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

Some other example where I still have the doubt

CODE 2:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
print(sc_X)
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
print(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)
```

I think that if I know like the general use for this function and what exactly does in general, I'll be good to go. But certaily I'd like to know what is doing on that code

Comment: Check on this link. It has a good example. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is also a nice check-up possibility: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

The `fit`-method is always to learn something in machine learning.

You normally have the following steps:

1. Seperate your data into two/three datasets
2. Pick one part of your data to learn/train something (normally `X_train`) with `fit`
3. Use the learned algorithm you predict something to unseen data (normally `X_test`) with `predict`

In your first example: `missingvalues.fit(X[:, 1:3])`
You are training `SimpleImputer`based on your data `X`where you are only using column `1,2,3`, with transform you used this training to overwrite this data.

In your second example: You are training `StandardScaler`with `X_train`and are using this training for both datasets `X_train, X_test`, the StandardScaler learnes from `X_train`that means if he learned that 10 has to be converted to 2, he will convert 10 to 2 in both sets `X_train, X_test`.

Comment: Thanks man! really cool. Btw if you have any cool resources for newbies in ML like my I'd really appreciate it. Anyway, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn uses Classes. See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more info about Classes in Python. For more info about `sklearn` in particular, take a look at this [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html).

Here's a short description of how you are using Classes in `sklearn`.

First you instantiate your `sklearn` Classes with `sc_X = StandardScaler()` or `missingvalues = SimpleImputer(...)`.

The objects, `sc_X` and `missingvalues`, each have methods. You can use the methods typing `object_name.method_name(...)`.  For example, you used the `fit_transform()` method of the `sc_X` instance when you typed, `sc_X.fit_transform(...)`. This method will take your data and return a scaled version of it. It both `fit`s (determines the scaling parameters) and `transform`s (applies scaling) to your data.  The `transform()` method will transform new data, using the same scaling parameters it learned for your previous data.

In the first example, you have separated the `fit` and `transform` methods into two separate lines, but the idea is similar -- you first learn the imputation parameters with the `fit` method, and then you transform your data.

By the way, I think `missingvalues = missingvalues.fit(X[:, 1:3])` could be changed to `missingvalues.fit(X[:, 1:3])`.

Comment: This certainly helped me a lot to undersand what is happening exactly, thanks man ;)